# DataGrip - show full table name in tabs and elsewhere

Tags: datagrip

Is it possible to always show full table names in DataGrip tabs and quick access menu? For example, when I press **command-E** it shows quick access to recent tables but it's sometimes truncating((3 dots)) full name *EVEN THOUGH* there so much more space available in the window. Thanks.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment I'm afraid.

Bug reports to follow:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-19857
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211371